# How to convert BigNumber returned by Truffle Console

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract

I have a simple contract `Foo` which is deployed to a Ganache network.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Foo {
    uint storageData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storageData = x;
    }

    function get() constant public returns (uint) {
        return storageData;
    }
}
```

Now when I want to interact with it using `truffle console`, first I set the value

```
truffle(development)> Foo.at("0x4d4337B075a442cF3351Fa11c425C350cE2984F5").set(123)
```

**Question 1:** Then I tried to retrieve that value but it is returning a `BignNumber`. Why is it not an integer?

```
truffle(development)> Foo.at("0x4d4337B075a442cF3351Fa11c425C350cE2984F5").get.call()
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 123 ] }
```

**Question 2:** How can you convert it to an integer or string?

```
truffle(development)> Foo.at("0x4d4337B075a442cF3351Fa11c425C350cE2984F5").get.call().toNumber()
TypeError: Foo.at(...).get.call(...).toNumber is not a function
```

Tried to `console.log` it after a `.toNumber`, it prints out the right value `123`, but why is it printing an `undefined` too?

```
truffle(development)> Foo.at("0x4d4337B075a442cF3351Fa11c425C350cE2984F5").get.call().then(a => console.log(a.toNumber()))
123
undefined
```

Comment: use `toNumber()` function: `count = await app.getCount; count.toNumber()`

Answer (score 5):

Some tips:

- have to do this asynchronously. Truffle makes the function thenable.
- don't need "call" explicitly because the get() is marked constant.
- once you have the BigNumber, then you can convert to something useful. Remember that JavaScript can't deal with 256-bit integers, so if you need to add/substract etc., always use the BigNumber library and the original value. Save this sort of conversion for making human-readable representations.

Try

```
var n;
var foo = Foo.at("0x4d4337B075a442cF3351Fa11c425C350cE2984F5");

foo.get().then(function(response) { 
  n = response.toString(10);
  console.log(n);
}
```

I just sketched it out to illustrate, so hopefully didn't flub the syntax.

Hope it helps.